# Foundation6/Sites Callout data-closable not working w/ live example

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I am trying to use a callout for foundation6/sites that can close using data-closable and data-close attributes, however I can't get it to work.

example: http://liveweave.com/Ls8x3p

As you can see in the example, the callout does gain the fade-out etc classes when clicking on the X, however it doesn't disappear.

What's missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing motion-ui. It's not natively included in the the foundation.css or .js.